# How to chunk a string containing characters with high code point?

Tags: javascript, string, surrogate-pairs

I have this string : `"397"`

The special character has the code point : `1114111`

When I chunk the string : `"397".match(/.{2}/g)`

I have this result : `['3\uDBFF', '\uDFFF9']`

But I want this result : `['3', '97']`

Thanks

Comment: could you try `console.log("397".match(/(.{2,3})/g, 2))` seems that character is 2 lengths long

Comment: You could use the `/gu` flags for unicode

Comment: Thank you I think it will work for what I'm doing

Answer (score 1):

you should try this:

```
"397".match(/.{2}/gu)
```